# Adding a remote theme to a GitHub enterprise instance?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, github-enterprise

I'm happily using a remote theme (like the excellent [Just the docs](https://pmarsceill.github.io/just-the-docs/)) for my public github pages (like [here](https://stwissel.github.io/vertx-sfdc-platformevents/)).
It is as simple as adding `remote_theme: pmarsceill/just-the-docs` to the `_config.yml` file.

Now I wanted to use this for a GitHub Enterprise (GHE) instance. I only got an unspecified error "Github page generation failed". I tried 3 options:

- Just have the entry `remote_theme: pmarsceill/just-the-docs`
- added the host `remote_theme: 'https://github.com/pmarsceill/just-the-docs'`
- Cloned the repository to GHE: `remote_theme: myuser/just-the-docs`

None of that worked.
What do I miss?

Comment: I tried all the options above and it seems that GHE expects a gem from RubyGems.